# Dense Countable basis on Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let say that I have a $H$ hilbert space and linear independent countable set  $\beta =\{ \beta_1 , \beta_2, \beta_3... \}$

such that $span(\beta)$ is dense set in H.

does $span(\beta-\beta_1) =span( \{ \beta_2, \beta_3... \})$

is dense set in $H$ ??

Comment: If you're talking of a basis as vector space (as opposed to basis of *topological* vector space or whatever), then it can't be: the set $\;\{\beta_2,\ldots\}\;$ cannot possibly generate $\;\beta_1\;$, lest $\;\beta\;$ was *not* linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks I will reformulate my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly instances where this is false.  As Jochen said, if this is an orthonormal basis, then $span(\beta-\beta_1) \subset \{\beta_1\}^\perp$ and so is not dense.  There are bases where it is possible to remove one or any finite number of terms and keep density, these are called *over complete* bases.

For instance in a RKHS, the span of the kernel functions are often overcomplete.

A more elementary example is bases as in the following:

If $\{\beta_n\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis then the span of $\{\beta_n - \beta_{n-1}\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ is dense in the Hilbert space and continues to span the space if any one element is removed.  This is from Halmos's "A Hilbert Space Problems Book".

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, $\beta_n$ are orthogonal then span$\lbrace \beta_2,\beta_3,\ldots\rbrace$ is not dense. The distance of $\beta_1$ to this set is $\|\beta_1\|$.